# How do i print rules being executed from excel in drools

Tags: java, drools

I am using Stateless session for Drools engine to execute rules.
I am reading rules from excel.I want to print following output. Basically what is being done in each step of rules execution.
E.g.

```
rule "Somerule_1"
            when
                          somecondition
            then
                     set some value
```

end

Drools code:

```
StatelessKieSession kSession = kieContainer.newStatelessKieSession("ksession-name");
    SomeObject so = new SomeObject();
    so.setValue(someValue);
   kSession.execute(so);
```

How do i print such output?

Comment: And what is not working?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to view the drl that gets generated from the spreadsheet.  SpreadsheetCompiler compiles xls to drl.

```
import org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler;    

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("your xls file");
SpreadsheetCompiler sc = new SpreadsheetCompiler();
String drl = sc.compile(fis, InputType.XLS);
```

This will generate your xls rules in the format:

```
rule "Somerule_1"
            when
                          somecondition
            then
                     set some value
```

Comment: @user2237700 - did this answer your question?